# How to retrieve an Element mixed children as text (JDOM)

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I have an XML like the following:

```
<documentation>
    This value must be <i>bigger</i> than the other.
</documentation>
```

Using JDOM, I can get the following text structures:

```
Document d = new SAXBuilder().build( new StringReader( s ) );
System.out.printf( "getText:          '%s'%n", d.getRootElement().getText() );
System.out.printf( "getTextNormalize: '%s'%n", d.getRootElement().getTextNormalize() );
System.out.printf( "getTextTrim:      '%s'%n", d.getRootElement().getTextTrim() );
System.out.printf( "getValue:         '%s'%n", d.getRootElement().getValue() );
```

which give me the following outputs:

```
getText:          '
    This value must be  than the other.
'
getTextNormalize: 'This value must be than the other.'
getTextTrim:      'This value must be  than the other.'
getValue:         '
    This value must be bigger than the other.
'
```

What I really wanted was to get the content of the element as a string, namely, `"This value must be <i>bigger</i> than the other."`. `getValue()` comes close but removes the `<i>` tag. I guess I wanted something like `innerHTML` for XML documents...

Should I just use an XMLOutputter on the contents? Or is there a better alternative?

Comment: Did you ever find a good answer to this question?

Comment: Look at Prashant Bhate's solution on this page, as I think it's the answer you're looking for:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910474/how-to-get-node-contents-from-jdom

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'd say you should change your document to

```
<documentation>
  <![CDATA[This value must be <i>bigger</i> than the other.]]>
</documentation>
```

in order to adhere to the XML specification. Otherwise `<i>` would be considered a child element of `<documentation>` and not content.

Comment: I guess this might indeed be the quickest way. Will try. On a side note, however, that documentation element is an `xsd:documentation`, whose content is declared as `any`, so the example is technically correct...

Comment: A child node in the middle of mixed content does NOT imply that the node is not actually a node.

Answer (score 0):

In JDOM pseudocode:

```
for Object o in d.getRootElement().getContents()
   if o instanceOf Element
      print <o.getName>o.getText</o.getName>
   else // it's a text
      print o.getText()
```

However, as [Prashant Bhate wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8854068/125617): content.getText() gives immediate text which is only useful fine with the leaf elements with text content.

Answer (score -1):

[Jericho HTML](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) is great for this sort of task.  You can accomplish exactly what you're trying to do with a code block like this:

```
String snippet = new Source(html).getFirstElement().getContent().toString();
```

It's also great for working with HTML in general because it doesn't try to force it into being XML...it deals with it much more leniently.

Comment: This is interesting, I'll give it a shot sometime. Right now I'd rather avoid adding another dependency to the project...

Comment: He has a JDom document, not HTML. XML != HTML.

Comment: @james.garriss Of course HTML and XML are different.  My point was that one could use Jericho to simplify a task that can be annoying to deal via cumbersome XML APIs.